# resumable link in downloadable product

Tags: downloadable

I want to create a store by magento and selling digital files (mp3, pdf, mkv, mp4). but i need to send resumable link to my customer by email. 
magento have not configuration for resumable link by defult. but i need to create resumable link
can you help me?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file

Comment: how to use it in magento?

Answer (score 2):

The download is generated in the `_processDownload()` function in `Mage_Downloadable_DownloadController` (see `app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/DownloadController.php` ).

What you need to do is, to create a new module with a controller override in it.

1.) Create your module ("Namespace_Module").

2.) add this to your `config.xml`

```
<config>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
        <downloadable>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Namespace_Module before="Mage_Downloadable">Namespace_Module</Namespace_Module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </downloadable>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

3.) create `Namespace/Module/controllers/DownloadController.php`

```
require_once 'Mage/Downloadable/controllers/DownloadController.php';
class Namespace_Module_DownloadController extends Mage_Downloadable_DownloadController {
    protected function _processDownload($resource, $resourceType) {
       //put your resume download logic here
   }
}
```